# Browser throws exception when connecting to my Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"myapp"` conf file.  I have ssl disabled, so all requests are routed through non-ssl connection.  Additionally, I have commented out the `ssl stapling on` directive.

Some people tell me (could be happening to all) that when they hit http://nickeleres.com , the browser throws a security exception.  I can't tell, I guess, because I added the site to my accepted sites list on all my browsers long ago.

What is causing this exception?

```
    server_tokens off; # for security-by-obscurity: stop displaying nginx version

    # this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    # HTTP
    server {
    #    listen 80 default_server; # if this is not a default server, remove "default_server"
    #    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
         listen 80;

        root /home/nickeleres; # root is irrelevant
        index /home/nickeleres; # this is also irrelevant

        server_name nickeleres.com; # the domain on which we want to host the application. Since we set "default_server" previously, nginx will answer a$

        # redirect non-SSL to SSL
    #    location / {
    #       return 301 https://nickeleres.com;
    #       rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    #   }

        # pass all requests to Meteor
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

            # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
            # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
            # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
            if ($uri != '/') {
                expires 30d;
            }
        }

    }

    # HTTPS server
    server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
        server_name nickeleres.com; # this domain must match Common Name (CN) in the SSL certificate

        root /home/nickeleres; # irrelevant
        index /home/nickeleres; # irrelevant

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt; # full path to SSL certificate and CA certificate concatenated together
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key; # full path to SSL key

        # performance enhancement for SSL
        # ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        # safety enhancement to SSL: make sure we actually use a safe cipher
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:kEDH+AESGCM:ECD$

        # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
        # to avoid ssl stripping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_stripping#SSL_stripping
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

        # If your application is not compatible with IE <= 10, this will redirect visitors to a page advising a browser update
        # This works because IE 11 does not present itself as MSIE anymore
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE" ) {
            return 303 https://browser-update.org/update.html;
        }

        # pass all requests to Meteor
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

            # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
            # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
            # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
            if ($uri != '/') {
                expires 30d;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have ssl disabled, so all requests are routed through non-ssl connection.

SSL is not disabled but active and is using a self-signed certificate which is causing the security warnings.

```
# HTTPS server
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here
    ...
```

And this is the part of your configuration, where you configure SSL. As you can see, SSL (and SPDY) are enabled on port 443.

What you probably disabled was the redirect from http:// to https://:

```
   # redirect non-SSL to SSL
#    location / {
#       return 301 https://nickeleres.com;
#       rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
#   }
```

But, since this is an permanent redirect (code 301 instead of 302) a browser caches this redirect and the next time the user will access the http:// site the browser will already know, that it should use the https:// site instead. And once it does it the invalid certificate will be found and the security warning issued.

To fix the problem remove the SSL (and SPDY) completely, so that the server will no longer listen on port 443.

Comment: so that means I should delete the line `listen 443 ssl spdy; # we enable SPDY here` and that is all?  then do `nginx -s reload` and restart upstart?

Comment: You should delete the complete server section which deals with port 443, not only the single line.